# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm fairly new to dash and I'm trying to follow along some of the more advanced guides (link: [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-a-dashboard-app-using-plotlys-dash-a-complete-guide-from-beginner-to-pro-61e890bdc423)) that look at multi page dashboards but seem to be falling over at every hurdle along the way.

I've managed to create my virtual environment install the required packages and I've just created the 'app.py' file but when I create and run the 'index.py' file I'm seeing the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app'
```

The app.py file I'm running was created with the following code:

```
import dash
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server
#app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True ####<-- tutorial said to run this line but as suppress was giving me errors I removed it
```

The 'index.py' file I'm running looks like:

```
from app import app
from app import server
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Dash Demo Graph',
                               style={
                                      'textAlign': 'center',
                                      "background": "yellow"}),
                       dcc.Graph(
                           id='graph-1',
                           figure={
                               'data': [
                                   {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'y': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 'type': 'line', 'name': 'value1'},
                                   {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'y': [12, 22, 36, 44, 49, 58, 73], 'type': 'line', 'name': 'value2'}
                               ],
                               'layout': {
                                   'title': 'Simple Line Graph',
                                     }
                                 }
                            ),

                            ], style={
                                "background": "#000080"}
                         )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I'm on a Windows machine using Jupyter Lab and python 3.8, the directory I'm running the code out of has the following folders and files in:

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
__pycache__
env
app.py
index.py
```

Any help on how I resolve this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share directory structure, and whether it is python 2 or 3 (python 3 doesn't support relative imports, rather supports relative imports only of the form "from . import *")

Comment: Where is the `index.py` file located? If you want to import from `app.py` like you do, it has to be in the same directory as the `app.py` file, and this directory has to be the main directory of the project, to which all the imports are relative.

Comment: @natka_m Sorry I've just updated my post, the index.py is in the same file as the app.py I just hadn't saved it but now I have I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: @Ehtesham Siddiqui I'm using Python 3.8 and the file directory is the last bit of the post that's in the coded area